# How to host nodejs services into nginx server in VirtualMachine?

Tags: node.js, nginx, postman

I wrote some nodejs services in my ubuntu local.Now I want to deploy my nodejs services into nginx server in my seperate VM.I set up the nginx in my virtual machine.How can I pull my nodejs services to nginx server and how to connect these api's through postman. I getting confusion at nginx config file.

Answer (score 2):

You should setup a reverse proxy with **nginx** to redirect the traffic to you **node** application. Install node on your VM, copy your application and install all the dependencies using `npm install`. Afterwards, you should start the node application using `node index.js` where `index.js` is the entry point of your application. You could also use a process manager such as **pm2** to start the application. Then, you have to setup the reverse proxy with nginx which is redirecting the traffic to the port of your application. (In your sample code **3000**). The application should now be available on the IP of your VM. Below you find a minimal example configuration for nginx.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```